# How to set data to this.$root when testing a VueJS component?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, vue.js, vuejs2

In VueJS 2.4, we can access root data from component thanks to this.$root, like in this JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bjg2yL1u/1/

If you click on a button, you can see 'orange' displayed in the console, which is a root data, not owned by the todo-item who triggered it.

Now I am inside a Jasmine test. This test works/run/is green properly.

But the console.log inside todo-item component outputs 'undefined'.

How can I inject data to this.$root instance when inside a test ?

```
describe("TodoItem", function() {

  var sut;
  var message = {text:'word'}

  beforeEach(function() {
    var Constructor = Vue.extend(TodoItem);
    sut = new Constructor({
      propsData: {
        todo: message,
      }
    }).$mount();
  });

  it("Should be able to reverse the given word", function() {
    // Given
    expect(sut.todo.text).toEqual('word');
    expect($(sut.$el).find('li').text()).toEqual('word');

    //When
    sut.reverseMessage();

    // Bang !! problem here. 'undefined' is printed, because there is nothing attached to this.$root when inside a test        

    // Then
    expect(sut.todo.text).toEqual('drow');

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a Vue from an extended component as you do here:

```
var Constructor = Vue.extend(TodoItem);
sut = new Constructor({
  propsData: {
    todo: message,
  }
}).$mount();
```

`Constructor` *is* the `$root`. There is no `display_light` property in your `TodoItem` component, and that is why the console.log prints `undefined`, because it literally is `undefined`.

If you want to add that data property to the component so that your test will work as expected (probably a bad idea) you could do it this way:

```
var Constructor = Vue.extend(TodoItem);
sut = new Constructor({
  propsData: {
    todo: {text: "hello world"},
  },
  data(){
    return {
      display_light: 'orange'
    }
  }
}).$mount();
```

Here is your [fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/bjg2yL1u/2/).